# Single pole or dual pole relay for switching a 3KW water heater? (UK)

Tags: electrical, water-heater, home-automation, relay

I have bought a Wifi controlled device to control a 3KW, 240V water heater (immersion heater) wirelessly but despite being advertised as 15A, it actually has a 13A relay which has "push fit" contacts. I'm not sure I trust it to run for several hours at its maximum rating. I want to replace the relay with a 25 or 30 amp rated relay which will therefore be operating well below it's rated load.

However the original isolator switch to the immersion heater is dual pole.  Should I therefore use a dual pole relay behind the isolator switch, or is this not necessary?  Is there any advantage of using dual pole in this scenario?   Given it's just a resistive load, I'm not sure if there's any particular merit of using a dual-pole relay in this situation?

Comment: Internally crossposted [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502564/single-pole-or-dual-pole-relay-for-switching-a-3-kw-water-heater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've been informed the your supply voltage is 240v to ground. Your isolation switch that is a double pole. They either switched the neutral or left the second pole vacant. There is no reason to use a double pole relay, a single pole will be just fine.

Just make sure your Wifi control device can deliver the necessary coil voltage/current for your new relay.

Comment: I agree but there 240v is more like our 120 so a double pole would not be of value with a 240v to ground system.

Comment: @EdBeal Some appliances are I believe required to have both phase and neutral isolated for maintenance, as the neutral is considered a live part. This isn't necessary for functional switching, though.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica That's probably what the isolation switch does.

Comment: The only place I know of where the neutral was required to be switched was fuel pumps but that requirement was removed in the last code cycle of the NEC.

Comment: @EdBeal In Australia, gas appliances need to switch both or be connected via plug+socket. Hazardous areas also require isolation of the neutral. For some reason I haven't found, controls in a fire pump system are installed in the neutral of a control circuit. Still haven't worked that one out.

Answer (score 2):

### That item probably should not connect to AC mains

Each country has apparatus to protect its citizen from dangerous products.  Most countries require good be certified by a competent independent testing lab such as [UL, CSA, BSI, TUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationally_Recognized_Testing_Laboratory) etc, and retail stores can get in big trouble for carrying uncertified items.  The EU allows companies to self-certify, but that only applies for businesses physically in the EU who ship from the EU to the EU.  And shipping via dropshippers like Amazon Warehouse does not count!

The CE mark (that self-certification mark) is worthless for things shipped from Amazon or outside the EU.

Certifying testing labs isn't really in USA OSHA's wheelhouse, but they've done a good job so everybody defers to them. Look for the mark of an NRTL.

From its configuration it's a USA/world market item.  The packaging/literature lied about its internal abilities.  It's a no-name or a brand you didn't think important enough to mention.

So this rings similar to what we see a lot of, which is that cheap Cheese junk brought in mail-order.  Search for a mark from an NRTL (CE isn't it). If you see ETL or TUV or UL, it's safe to let it touch mains power.  Otherwise, heck no - keep it on the low voltage side of the certified wall wart. Have it use low voltage to operate a certified relay.

Components have their own certification system; one common one us RU (with a Russian R for some reason). That is UL's component listing. Ideally you'll see a mark like that on every component capable of taking a mark, and certainly the relay.

### You're right, the relay isn't strong enough

Really, you want a margin of safety *anyway*, even with certified stuff.

I recommend you go a somewhat different way. Rather than having the "smart WiFi device" switch the power directly, have it switch a (certified quality) relay/contactor which in turn switches the power.  If it were America I would recommend a Rib or Aube, which operate on 12-24V and fit right up into our style of junction boxes.  I don't know what equivalent equipment you have for mains switching in the UK/EU market, but I'm sure there's something.

Comment: Generally speaking, they'd get a DIN rail contactor for that job

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm intending. I have ordered a 30amp Omron brand relay (which are a very reputable brand here in Europe) who are also well known for making heathcare equipment. The device itself is also a known brand (Sonoff), but I simply don't trust running it at 100% of it's rated capacity in a hot cupboard.

Comment: @NickG Oh, well done!  Yes, I recognized that brand even from here in the States. Yes, Sonoff is all about their WiFi tech, and they're good and famous at that, but *not* so all about bothering to make a product UL would ever certify as safe.  Their customers don't care, so they don't. My message to you as a customer is, "care". Or, in the alternate, keep it on the 12V side of the wall wart lol. Hard to get in too much trouble in low voltage.